# Is there a free tool for the Rich Text Editor to embed youtube videos?

Tags: wysiwyg, video, richtext

I'd like to be able to allow clients to use the Rich Text Editor to paste the embed code from youtube or vimeo. Instructing them to use "View Code" then paste is going to be difficult!

Is this possible natively, and if not does a free tool for the RTE exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I'm aware there isn't a free plugin available currently that allows for this feature and it's not catered for out-of-the-box.

However it would be possible for a tool to be developed and added to the tool library - I've just taken a quick look though the `link` plugin - this could easily be adapted to work for YouTube / Vimeo links if you feel so inclined.

The full dev instructions for the API can be found here - http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/rte_tools.html - however it's probably easiest to edit one of the existing tools in this case.

Alternatively DevDemon's Channel Videos is free and allows the user to instantly add videos - http://www.devdemon.com/channel_videos/ - however this wouldn't be integrated into RTE.

Comment: I had a feeling this would be the answer, but thanks for the useful suggestions!

Comment: is there a simpler way?how about including an iframe or blockquote ?

Answer (score 2):

Channel Videos is a great solution for simplifying the process of embedding videos for clients.It has a visual interface so that the client can see a thumbnail of the video prior to publishing. You can search videos by keyword from the CP or just add the Youtube url - which is a lot easier than customising the embed code and copy/pasting.

Additionally you can set the variables for the video height/width etc within your templates which will prevent the end user from embedding videos that are too large or too small -  that's something you could not control with a copy/paste of the embed code.

And it supports both Youtube and Vimeo.